# Rails CSV file upload problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, csv

I'm trying to upload a CSV file(without headers) to a form in Rails, and then change my database based on that file's contents.

Now, the problem I'm having is that I know my routes must be correct, because I'm able to get to the correct method...but, my @imported variable is saying it is nil even when I upload a file.

Is there any help I can get for this?  This will be my first file upload in rails, so we can cross this milestone together...

Here is the form in my view, mapped to the #ship action:

```
<%= form_for @import, :url => {:action => "ship", :controller => "imports"} do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :import %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And here is the corresponding method in my controller:

```
def ship
   @import = CSV.read(params[:file])
   @import.each do |i|
      Product.ship(@import[i][0]) #I believe the #read method imports
   end                              #CSV files as an array of arrays
  redirect_to "/"                   #But I have yet to get past the 
 end                                #first line, so I'm unsure
```

Comment: possible that `:import` param is not permitted in your controller?

Comment: Would that just be as simple as adding params.permit.require(:import) to my controller?  I didn't realize import needed that.

Comment: yes, and a way to check that is to see whether your logs return `unpermitted parameter :import` following the `POST` action.

Comment: Well, that changed my error to "no implicit conversion of hash to string".  Which is odd, since I was certain CSV.read would turn it into an array of arrays rather than a hash.

Comment: `@import` vs `@imported`. Which is it? Also I think it should be `params[:import][:import]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sergio Tulentsev is right. You need to use `params[:import][:import]`. The first `import` being the name of your resource (comes from `form_for @import`, the second `import` being the field name (coming from `f.file_field :import`).

More info at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files

Comment: Well, that definitely got me where I needed to go.  Thank you.